# Receive PDF file and forward it without altering it

Tags: mule

I need to expose a webservice where users can send me a PDF file via a POST request.
I don't want to alter this file. Just store it in a container on the cloud.

Here is the curl I use to test my service :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/pdf"  'http://localhost:9302/billing/1/storeInvoice/user/0750102626/invoice/666' --data-binary /Users/manu/Desktop/toto.pdf
```

And here is the XML code of my flow :

```
<flow name="storebill">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${inbound.host}" port="9302" path="storeInvoice/" method="POST" contentType="application/pdf"/>
    <custom-transformer class="BuildFileNameFromRequestPath" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="myHost" port="80" path="#[flowVars['fileName']" contentType="application/pdf" method="PUT"/>
    <exception-strategy ref="genericExceptionStrategy" />
</flow>
```

The file is well stored in my openstack container but it's completely badly encoded.
When I download a file that I'd previously stored, I'm not able to read it on my laptop.

PS : When I upload my local PDF via curl in the openstack container, it's well encoded.

Code of the BuildFileNameFromRequestPath transformer :

```
public class BuildFileNameFromRequestPath extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws BusinessException {

        String request = message.getInboundProperty("http.request");
        StoreBillInfo result = getRestInfo(request);

        if (result != null) {
            message.setProperty(VariableNamesConstant.VAR_STOREBILLINFO, result, PropertyScope.INVOCATION);
        } else {
            throw new BusinessException(ErrorCode.ERR400);
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("length payload : " + message.getPayloadAsBytes().length);
            return message.getPayloadAsBytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BusinessException(ErrorCode.ERR400);
        }
    }
}
```

The getRestInfo is only a method to extract some information from the path in order to construct the file name of the pdf.

Comment: Can you show what's inside `BuildFileNameFromRequestPath`?

Comment: ok, I put it on the original question...

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with the message payload with `message.getPayloadAsBytes()`. You're deserializing the stream for no good reason, and potentially mess up the encoding.

Instead of using a custom transformer, use a `set-variable` element with a MEL expression that statically calls `getRestInfo`.